# python execute def from vscode terminal

Tags: python, function, terminal

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pK1k4.png)
so i've been trying to execute a def from the vscode terminal and it didn't worked like the output is telling me that something is missing but I dunno what, can someone explain please, i'm a bit confused rn. I haven't tried anything.

Comment: Please post your code and output as text. Screenshots of text can not be accepted on Stack Overflow.

Comment: You cannot invoke python functions directly from the command line. You can only call functions your `carre` and `calctva` functions from other python code.

Comment: If you want to invoke certain methods you have to invoke the script `python module1.py`. You can then add arguments after the file name `python module1.py arg1 arg2` and those will be available in python using `sys.argv` -> `[arg1, arg2]`

Comment: That is an OS she'll, not an interactive python interpreter session. Use `python` to enter that